# Olympus BH-2 Microscope and an Olympus E-3 DSLR

Tags: microscopy

I have an Olympus BH-2 Microscope and an Olympus E-3 DSLR. What do I need to connect the 2?

I think need:
Trinocular head,
Lens adapter,
Camera adapter,
Photo eyepiece.

Is this everything I need? How do I find the particular part/model numbers?

Comment: The best way probably is consulting with Olympus support.

Answer (score 1):

When I had that microscope and E-3 (still have) I used [photomicro adapter for old OM cameras](http://www.alanwood.net/photography/olympus/photomicro-adapter-l.html) and adapter OM->4/3. Of course, trinocular head too. I hadn't photo eyepice that days but if you have it your microphotoshoot can be easier.